# Preserving session in HttpClient

Tags: java, android, cookies, web-scraping, httpclient

I'm attempting to log into a wesbite. On my first request, I do a POST on the login page with the username and password and log in successfully. Using the same instance of HttpClient, I do a second request on a different page on the website, this time a GET request, but this time, the page returned is not logged in. I think this is due to the fact that the second request is being done in a new session.

After the first request, among the many cookies it returns, this is the session ID cookie:

```
name: ASPSESSIONIDSCSCSBCS
value: GBAJALJBOGKBFLAELPNKEDOE
```

And after the second request, among many other cookies, I have two different session ID cookies:

```
name: ASPSESSIONIDSCSCSBCS
value: GBAJALJBOGKBFLAELPNKEDOE

name: ASPSESSIONIDSCSCSBCS
value: MBAJALJBDBOKPEHNCDDFOCBC
```

I'm assuming that because the session id is different during the second request, it ignores cookies with the first session id.

How do I fix this?

Edit: This is my code

```
public HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
public CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
public HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

//The first request 
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.deeproute.com/deeproute/default.asp");
 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cookieexists","false"));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", mUser));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mPassword));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subbera", "Login"));

 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
 res = httpclient.execute(httppost, localContext);

//The second request
 HttpGet rosterGet = new HttpGet("http://deeproute.com/deeproute/?sel=rosterlook&myleagueno=6&myteamno=12");
 res = httpclient.execute(rosterGet, localContext);
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/23251941/32453

Answer (score 0):

I think you should overwrite cookieStore with a

```
 cookieStore = (BasicCookieStore) httpClient.getCookieStore();
```

only after success in login..
after that I think you should set again the Context with new cookieStore..
Let me know!